# Writing regex for string containing no only numbers

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex containing not only digits `[0-9]`. How can I do that without explicitly specifying all possible charaters in a group. Is it possible to do through lookahead/lookbehind? Examples:

```
034987694 - doesn't match
23984576s9879 - match
rtfsdbhkjdfg - match
=-0io[-09uhidkbf - match
9347659837564983467 - doesn't match
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @anubhava yes, I have.

Comment: Then you should show your attempted regex in question

Comment: @anubhava Ok, why `^(?!\\d+$).*$` works fine, but `^(?!\\d+).*$` doesn't?

Comment: @user3663882 `^(?!\\d+).*$` this states that there should not be integers at the start of string.but you need to make sure it is not the only thing in the string,so it should be complemented with `$`

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!\\d+$).*$
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/1

The negative will lookahead will check if the string doesnt have `integers` from start to end.You need `$` to make sure the check is till end or else it will just check at the start.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to detect whether the string is not numbers-only, then you can simply test for `/\D/` - "succeed if there is a non-digit anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

Why not check if it only contains digits, if not it matches

```
String[] strings = {"034987694", "23984576s9879",
    "rtfsdbhkjdfg",
    "=-0io[-09uhidkbf",
    "9347659837564983467"};
for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", s, !s.matches("\\d*"));
}
```

**output**

```
034987694 = false
23984576s9879 = true
rtfsdbhkjdfg = true
=-0io[-09uhidkbf = true
9347659837564983467 = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below,

```
string.matches(".*\\D.*");
```

This expects atleast 1 non-digit character.